# Is it possible to add firebase push notification to edx app ,while I am using edx build.sh for asset and package change?

Tags: android, edx

I am using edx app and for changing the package name updating assets we are using build.sh script. But now we want to use firebase push-notification inside it. For this case, we need to sync our project with a firebase.But on development time package name is "org.edx.mobile" and we need "org.xx.mobile" inside firebase.

Comment: You can create your own firebase project for notification and use google-services.json file in your project.

Comment: I have created a new project in firebase , but adding google-services.json is not working ,means not creating refresh token /not syncing with Firebase project.

Comment: Make sure you have the same package name in JSON file and project Gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

```
After going through the firebase documentation.I found out firebase only need application ID ,not package name for integration so app can have different package name and different application in buid.gradle.Generally its preferable to use same apllication id as of package name.But if we have similar situation we can handle it.Find implementation as below:-
In project level Build.gradle
    defaultConfig {
            applicationId "org.XXX.mobile"
    }

Add  google plugin in same file
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

    Now Add google-services.json in your project root folder ,which you got from firebase console.Sync your gradle now.Now you can see the Firebase service is service started successfully in your log.
```